# Able to view records, but unable to create particular RT

Tags: record-type, tasks, record-access-level

Just a quick question

We have approx. 10 RT on the tasks, not every RT is assigned to a profile. Now I know how to assign record types by profile, however my question is, the users would like to see the records assigned to this particular RT, however they don’t want to see the RT from the pick list  (when creating a new task)

Can this be done ?

Comment: Do I read your question correctly: you want users to only be able to see records with record types they are allowed to create?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is how the recordType mechanism works by default.

- Adding the RT to the profile gives the users the create capability for that RT, and so it will appear in the RT pick-list when creating.
- Users can view records assigned to any RT (dependant on other security settings) even if they are not assigned to their profile.

There is an overview of RT access [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=permissions_record_type_access.htm&language=en_US) in the docs.